# Restoring Custom Directives that Manipulate the DOM

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, directive

I have two custom element directives:

```
<my-directive-parent></my-directive-parent> //only one
```

and

```
<my-directive-child></my-directive-child> //variable count
```

The `my-directive-parent` directive has its own *controller* and *templateUrl* properties defined in its *directive definition object*. The `my-directive-child` directive has its own *link*, *scope*, *templateUrl* and *require* properties defined in its *directive definition object*. The fourth parameter passed into the link function is the parent `my-directive-parent`'s controller. This is working as expected.

Based on user input, instances of `my-directive-child` are appended to or removed from the parent `my-directive-parent` DOM via the `my-directive-parent`'s controller. Since I'm using ngView for the top-level page, changing pages results in Angular automatically cleaning up the various directives and their controllers of the top-level page. Upon returning, the controller for the page re-runs, but the user appended views do not show up (since they were previously wiped out automatically by Angular). I'm using a service which holds the data representing the collection of `my-directive-child` instances that were previously added.

My issue lies in restoring the `my-directive-child` directives based on this cached service data. Currently, when the `my-directive-parent` directive's controller is run, I'm getting the service data array that represents the instances to be added, looping through it, and adding a new `my-directive-child` instance to the DOM. This is working, but upon restoring each instance I need to pre-populate it with data that was previously entered by the user (of which is recorded in the service). Currently, when adding to the DOM this way each instance is in a "blank" state instead of a desired pre-populated state.

So I have the data needed to recreate the child directive instances, but I'm unable to pre-populate them with the necessary data.

I've tried to place a custom attr on the `my-directive-child` in an effort to forward the data to the instance's scope, but I learned from Angular's API docs that:

> The new scope rule does not apply for the root of the template since the root of the template always gets a new scope

Questions:

- Is my approach wrong? What should I be doing?
- Is there a way to pass attrs defined on the actual element directive into the directive's scope that represents the inner template HTML?
- How do I ensure a custom directive within a custom directive properly pre-populates itself?

Thank you in advance for any ideas, answers, or thoughts that might lead to a solid solution.

Comment: It's hard to understand what you're doing.  Are the `my-directive-child` elements in the template of `my-directive-parent`?  Why aren't you using `ng-repeat` on `my-directive-child`?

Comment: @JasonGoemaat No the `my-directive-child` elements are not initially in the `my-directive-parent` template, but are later added into it based on user input. As mentioned, my approach may be wrong. I'm now thinking your mentioned `ng-repeat` approach may be the way to go. Basically, the "items" count would be 0 initially (no children would show) but would update based on user input and ng-repeat would auto update the DOM, correct?

Comment: I think that would be better, making use of `ng-repeat` and letting the data drive the creation of your `my-directive-child` elements.  Each should have an inherited child scope with access to the item from `ng-repeat`, which you can set in an attribute if you need the child to create an isolated scope.  Let me know more about any trouble you have getting to that data or start a new question for it.